# Get mask of image without using OpenCV

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying the following to get the mask out of this image, but unfortunately I fail.

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.color
import skimage.filters
import skimage.io

# get filename, sigma, and threshold value from command line
filename = 'pathToImage'

# read and display the original image
image = skimage.io.imread(fname=filename)
skimage.io.imshow(image)
# blur and grayscale before thresholding
blur = skimage.color.rgb2gray(image)
blur = skimage.filters.gaussian(blur, sigma=2)
# perform inverse binary thresholding
mask = blur < 0.8
# use the mask to select the "interesting" part of the image
sel = np.ones_like(image)
sel[mask] = image[mask]

# display the result
skimage.io.imshow(sel)
```

How can I obtain the mask?

[image] [image]

Is there a general approach that would work for this image as well. without custom fine-tuning and changing parameters?
[image]

Comment: A possible approach is load image, convert to grayscale, Gaussian blur, threshold to obtain a binary image, morph open to remove small noise, find contours, and sort from largest to smallest contour area, the largest contour should be your desired object. Then simply draw this contour with white onto a black mask image to get your result

Answer (score 1):

1. Apply high contrast (maximum possible value)

[image: s1]

2. convert to black & white image using high threshold (I've used 250)

[image: s2]

3. min filter (value=8)

[image: s3]

4. max filter (value=8)

[image: s4]

Comment: Is there a general approach that would work also for the other image (please see edit) without manually modifying parameters ?

Comment: if the object colors matches the background you will need different approach. why don't you put all the odd cases you want this to work correctly with, and then I will try to give you a general approach.

Comment: I think that all of my cases fall into these two categories.

Comment: Why don't you want to use OpenCV ?

Comment: My app cannot support it given the flow already inplace

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can get a rough mask using only the `skimage` library methods:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread, imsave
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.filters import gaussian
from skimage.morphology import dilation, erosion, selem
from skimage.measure import find_contours
from skimage.draw import polygon

def get_mask(img):
    kernel = selem.rectangle(7, 6)
    dilate = dilation(canny(rgb2gray(img), 0), kernel)
    dilate = dilation(dilate, kernel)
    dilate = dilation(dilate, kernel)
    erode = erosion(dilate, kernel)
    mask = np.zeros_like(erode)
    rr, cc = polygon(*find_contours(erode)[0].T)
    mask[rr, cc] = 1
    return gaussian(mask, 7) > 0.74

def save_img_masked(file):
    img = imread(file)[..., :3]
    mask = get_mask(img)
    result = np.zeros_like(img)
    result[mask] = img[mask]
    imsave("masked_" + file, result)

save_img_masked('belt.png')
save_img_masked('bottle.jpg')
```

Resulting `masked_belt.png`:

[image]

Resulting `masked_bottle.jpg`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses the fact that the background changes color only very slowly. Here I apply the gradient magnitude to each of the channels and compute the norm of the result, giving me an image highlighting the quicker changes in color. The watershed of this (with sufficient tolerance) should have one or more regions covering the background and touching the image edge. After identifying those regions, and doing a bit of cleanup we get these results (red line is the edge of the mask, overlaid on the input image):

[image: case 1 output]

[image: case 2 output]

I did have to adjust the tolerance, with a lower tolerance in the first case, more of the shadow is seen as object. I think it should be possible to find a way to set the tolerance based on the statistics of the gradient image, I have not tried.

There are no other parameters to tweak here, the minimum object area, 300, is quite safe; an alternative would be to keep only the one largest object.

This is the code, using [DIPlib](https://diplib.org) (disclaimer: I'm an author). `out` is the mask image, not the outline as displayed above.

```py
import diplib as dip
import numpy as np

# Case 1:
img = dip.ImageRead('Pa9DO.png')
img = img[362:915, 45:877]  # cut out actual image
img = img(slice(0,2))       # remove alpha channel
tol = 7

# Case 2:
#img = dip.ImageRead('jTnVr.jpg')
#tol = 1

# Compute gradient
gm = dip.Norm(dip.GradientMagnitude(img))
# Compute watershed with tolerance
lab = dip.Watershed(gm, connectivity=1, maxDepth=tol, flags={'correct','labels'})
# Identify regions touching the image edge
ll = np.unique(np.concatenate((
      np.unique(lab[:,0]),
      np.unique(lab[:,-1]),
      np.unique(lab[0,:]),
      np.unique(lab[-1,:]))))
# Remove regions touching the image edge
out = dip.Image(lab.Sizes(), dt='BIN')
out.Fill(1)
for l in ll:
   if l != 0:  # label zero is for the watershed lines
      out = out - (lab == l)
# Remove watershed lines
out = dip.Opening(out, dip.SE(3, 'rectangular'))
# Remove small regions
out = dip.AreaOpening(out, filterSize=300)
# Display
dip.Overlay(img, dip.Dilation(out, 3) - out).Show()
```

Comment: Hi Cris, is it necessary to cut the actual image? I would like to avoid that if possible

Comment: @azal That line is necessary because you posted a screen shot of the image displayed with Matplotlib, with a border and axes around it. It is cutting off these axes and border. I’m pretty sure that the image you posted is not the one you are actually processing. This was my way of approximating the actual image you need to process. You should leave that out.

Comment: could you elaborate/show a way to calc the tolerance if possible?

Comment: @azal I haven't had time to think about that yet. The shadow in that first image is quite sharp, it'll be hard to know if it's a sharp shadow or a product. I think a 2nd order derivative might be meaningful, but I would need to give that some thought to give a concrete idea.

Comment: was not able to install the library via pip install diplib

Comment: @azal: What is the error message? What version of Python are you using? DIPlib is supported on 3.7 to 3.9, on Linux, macOS and Windows. On Linux, 3.6 is also supported. On other systems or other versions of Python you'd have to build the library yourself.

Comment: it worked now; it was something on my end. Any ideas on the dynamic calculation of the tolerance using derivatives?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: loci/formats/meta/MetadataStore
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: loci.formats.meta.MetadataStore.  I am getting this error with python 3.7 when using dip.ImageRead

Comment: @azal PNG images are read through the Bio-Formats package, which needs to be installed separately. Run `python -m diplib download_bioformats` from the command line, as described here: https://pypi.org/project/diplib/

Comment: Im getting this after trying to install the module /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3: No module named diplib. diplib is installed

Comment: @azal If Python doesn’t recognize the `DIPlib` module, it is installed either in a virtual environment, or for a different version of Python. Please check how it is installed. If you open an issue on GitHub it will be easier to help you find a solution. https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/issues

Comment: @azal Also, you can read the image using any other library, a NumPy array can be used as input to any DIPlib function.

Comment: I finally fixed all the issues but this line  gm = dip.Norm(dip.GradientMagnitude(img)) crashes in my PyQT app : (

Comment: @azal Obviously it's not supposed to cause crashes. But I don't know how to help you with that given so little information. If you can make a [mre], and submit it as an issue on GitHub, I will look into it. https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/issues